# Want to show Uploading progress to the user through Retrofit 1

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, image-uploading

I want to upload images through `Retrofit 1` and show the images uploading status of all the images.

**Preoblem**

1:-Listener immediate give value 0 to 100.

2:-even images are uploading it shows 100% status.

Here my `TypedFileWithProgressListener` class witch i used to calculate to bytes

```
public class TypedFileWithProgressListener extends TypedFile {

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

private final ProgressListener listener;

public TypedFileWithProgressListener(String mimeType, File file, ProgressListener listener) {
    super(mimeType, file);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(super.file());
    long total = 0;
    try {
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            total += read;
            this.listener.transferred(total);
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

public ProgressListener getListener() {
    return listener;
}
 }
```

Here listner that listen progress

```
public interface ProgressListener {
void transferred(long num);
 }
```

And now i call Api through Retrofit 1 and want to show every image status how mutch it uploaded.

```
 RestClient.getApiService().uploaddatafiles(new TypedFileWithProgressListener("multipart/form-data", cnicfrontimage, new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    prgCnicFront.setProgress((int) ((num / (float) cnicfrontimage.length()) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }),
                    new TypedFileWithProgressListener("multipart/form-data", cnicbackimage, new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    prgCnicBack.setProgress((int) ((num / (float) cnicbackimage.length()) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }),
                    new TypedFileWithProgressListener("multipart/form-data", vehiclefrontimage, new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    prgVehicleFront.setProgress((int) ((num / (float) vehiclefrontimage.length()) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }),
                    new TypedFileWithProgressListener("multipart/form-data", vehiclebackimage, new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    prgVehicleBack.setProgress((int) ((num / (float) vehiclebackimage.length()) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }),
                    new TypedFileWithProgressListener("multipart/form-data", registrationcopyimage, new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    prgRegistration.setProgress((int) ((num / (float) registrationcopyimage.length()) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }), new TypedFileWithProgressListener("multipart/form-data", driverimage, new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    prgProfile.setProgress((int) ((num / (float) driverimage.length()) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }),
                    new TypedString(edtCnicFirst.getText().toString() + "-" + edtCnicSecond.getText().toString() + "-" + edtCnicThird.getText().toString()),
                    new TypedString(String.valueOf(vehicle_type)), new TypedString(accessToken), new TypedString(String.valueOf(edtExpiryDate.getText().toString())),
                    new TypedString(String.valueOf(BrandsTypes.get(spinnerBrands.getSelectedItemPosition()))),
                    new TypedString(String.valueOf(confiqData.getData().getVehicleAvailableModles().get(spinnerBrands.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1).getId())),
                    new TypedString(String.valueOf(vehiclenumber)), new Callback<String>() {
                        private JSONObject jObj;
                        int flag = 0;

                        @Override
                        public void success(String response, Response r) {

                            try {
                                jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                                flag = jObj.getInt("flag");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(ActivityDriverProfile.this, "Try again Information not upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
```

Here my ApiRequest

```
 @Multipart
@POST("/upload_images_and_data")
void uploaddatafiles(@Part("cnic_front") TypedFile cnicfront, @Part("cnic_back") TypedFile cnicback, @Part("car_front") TypedFile carfront, @Part("car_back") TypedFile carback, @Part("registration_docs") TypedFile registrationdoc, @Part("driver_image") TypedFile driverimage, @Part("cnic") TypedString cnic, @Part("fuel_type") TypedString fueltype, @Part("access_token") TypedString accesstoken,@Part("cnic_expiry_date") TypedString idcardexpiry,@Part("vehicle_brand") TypedString vehiclebrand,@Part("vehicle_brand_id") TypedString vehiclebrandid,@Part("vehicle_number") TypedString vehiclenumver, Callback<String> callback);
```

Comment: Anyone here to reply?

Comment: Stable version of Retrofit 2 was released back in [2016](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-200-2016-03-11) why do you still want stick to **Retrofit 1**? Any specific reason for that? And your question is about version 1 why did you tag Retrofit version 2 tag in your question?

Comment: @Shashanth i am using retrofit 1 in my whole project so i want want to use retrofit1 otherwise i replace it to retro1 it required many changes.
i tag retro 2 i think many of then may be migrate to retro 2 for facing this issue.